# PHP, cookies, and rapid browser refresh

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

For my login system, I have a token value that changes every time authentication occurs. Authentication occurs every time any page is accessed (by looking for token cookies and sessions ad such), as well as every `$.ajax` call (my thought is that I would want to ensure the user is authenticated at all times, and if ever authentication fails with a bad token or series or whatever, the system would automatically completely log out). During the authentication process, when it is determined that the current session is valid, a new token is generated, and that token is set as a cookie as well as updated in a MySQL table, as such:

```
$newtoken = hash("sha256", mt_rand());
my_mysqli_query($link, 
                'UPDATE _rememberme SET token = "'.$newtoken.'", lastupdated = "'.now().'" 
                 WHERE series = "'.$series.'" AND email = "'.$email.'"');
setmycookie("token", $newtoken, 7);
```

When I rapidly refresh the browser, it ends up that the MySQL token and the cookie token do not match. I *think* that the problem is that during a rapid refresh, the MySQL table gets updated, but then a refresh occurs and the script aborts before updating the cookie. This causes future authentication failures because the cookie token doesn't match the MySQL token.

I would really appreciate some ideas on how to survive a user rapidly refreshing their browser.

I have researched this issue and had little success in finding a solution.

Comment: How do you go about validating the token? Is the `lastupdated` timestamp involved in validation in such a way that two modifications in the same second would cause a collision? Please post that code as well - it seems unlikely that refreshing is occurring quickly enough to halt execution between the `UPDATE` statement and the `setcookie()` call, and more likely related to validation logic.

Comment: No, lastuppdated isn't involved.  It's more just for informational purposes.  I'm not at home with my code right now, but basically, I was unnecessarily assigning a session ID based off the cookie, followed by session_start(), followed by regenerate_session_id().  By choosing to remove the ID assignment and regeneration, the issue disappears.  I know this isn't the best solution, and the site won't be live for a long while, so I still have time to research.

Comment: Sir, are you sure you don't cut the token at a specific lenghts? Or maybe your db is setted to accept only one part of the token, cutting the rest. Please post also some output

Comment: @mrphuzz You should post your solution as an answer below then when you get a chance.

Comment: You change the token every time a page is requested? In what way does this add any value to the process?

Comment: There is also little to no value in using such an expensive hashing algorithm for the session token, since it isn't going to be any more secure.

Comment: @mrphuzz: I'm sorry if you had issues with my edit.  Your title used the same words as your question's tags, and in most cases, but not all, they're considered redundant.  Also, in the future, you should write your questions as concisely as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution adds nothing to the security, and adds a great source of headache to your users.

If you use *PHP Sessions*, you don't have to rely on multiple cookies, and don't have to hash everything on every access. Having sessions in place will increase the security, as your users will not be able to change their session variables. A cookie is user-modifiable, so you can't blindly trust them. A user can change the PHPSESSION cookie, though, but the chances of changing the session to another one is so, so small that is almost impossible.

With your current code, if a user opens a link on a new tab, and before the request returns he opens another link, he will be logged off. The cookie will change on the first request, but before the browser gets the new value, the user submits another request with the old cookie. The new value is on the database, the new request with the old value is processed, and the session is invalidated. Another unhappy user confused because he was randomly logged off.